# longtable and colortbl

Tags: longtable, r, colortbl

I'm trying to color specific rows (with MES >= 8) but for some reason, it doesn't work for the first line. I'm running a R Markdown (xtable package to create the table).

```
print(xtable(m8.c(SC), digits = 0, caption = "Atendimentos superados (\\%)"),     add.to.row = list(list(which(m8.c(SC)$MES >= 8)-1), "\\rowcolor{red} "), tabular.environment = "longtable")
```

The code generated with xtable is

```
% latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Wed Feb 01 15:37:07 2017
\begin{longtable}{rrlrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & CIDADE1 & UOR & MODAL & MES & Atend & Valor & AtSup & Turmas & TurAcu \\ 
  \rowcolor{red}  \hline
    1 & 1 & C. A. FLORIANÓPOLIS & 2 & 8 & 2725 & 2540 & 7 & 14 & 28 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 2 & 1 & C. A. FLORIANÓPOLIS & 2 & 10 & 2161 & 2126 & 2 & 0 & 28 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 3 & 4 & C. A. BRUSQUE & 1 & 11 & 30 & 27 & 11 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  4 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 6 & 4648 & 2565 & 81 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 5 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 8 & 1827 & 1399 & 31 & 0 & 7 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 6 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 9 & 1596 & 1314 & 21 & 0 & 7 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 7 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 10 & 1196 & 1166 & 3 & 0 & 7 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 8 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 11 & 1191 & 926 & 29 & 0 & 7 \\ 
  9 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 6 & 233 & 120 & 94 & 1 & 2 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 10 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 8 & 144 & 72 & 100 & 0 & 2 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 11 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 9 & 157 & 81 & 94 & 0 & 2 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 12 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 10 & 120 & 80 & 50 & 0 & 2 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 13 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 11 & 203 & 108 & 88 & 0 & 2 \\ 
  14 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 6 & 265 & 144 & 84 & 1 & 2 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 15 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 8 & 179 & 60 & 198 & 1 & 3 \\ 
  \rowcolor{red} 16 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 9 & 120 & 69 & 74 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 17 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 10 & 120 & 43 & 179 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 18 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 11 & 116 & 43 & 170 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 19 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 8 & 228 & 120 & 90 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 20 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 9 & 168 & 96 & 75 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 21 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 10 & 129 & 90 & 43 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 22 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 11 & 152 & 78 & 95 & 0 & 4 \\ 
  23 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 7 & 55 & 52 & 6 & 1 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 24 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 8 & 112 & 40 & 180 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 25 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 9 & 74 & 32 & 131 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 26 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 10 & 98 & 35 & 180 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 27 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 11 & 84 & 28 & 200 & 0 & 3 \\ 
  28 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 7 & 642 & 408 & 57 & 5 & 11 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 29 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 8 & 814 & 522 & 56 & 0 & 11 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 30 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 9 & 663 & 444 & 49 & 1 & 12 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 31 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 10 & 690 & 483 & 43 & 0 & 12 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 32 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 11 & 651 & 434 & 50 & 0 & 12 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 33 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 8 & 78 & 45 & 73 & 0 & 2 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 34 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 10 & 31 & 18 & 72 & 0 & 2 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 35 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 2 & 11 & 34 & 18 & 89 & 0 & 2 \\ 
  36 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 2 & 4 & 684 & 672 & 2 & 0 & 4 \\ 
  37 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 7 & 72 & 60 & 20 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 38 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 8 & 99 & 54 & 83 & 1 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 39 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 9 & 81 & 79 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\ 
  \rowcolor{red} 40 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 10 & 66 & 63 & 5 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 41 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 11 & 69 & 63 & 10 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 42 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 8 & 93 & 76 & 22 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 43 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 9 & 108 & 95 & 14 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 44 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 10 & 93 & 76 & 22 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 45 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 11 & 90 & 76 & 18 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 46 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 8 & 96 & 60 & 60 & 1 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 47 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 9 & 99 & 82 & 21 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 48 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 10 & 81 & 66 & 23 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 49 & 13 & C. A. LAGES & 4 & 11 & 78 & 66 & 18 & 0 & 4 \\ 
  50 & 14 & C. A. LAGUNA & 1 & 7 & 1127 & 594 & 90 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 51 & 14 & C. A. LAGUNA & 1 & 8 & 1677 & 1488 & 13 & 1 & 5 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 52 & 14 & C. A. LAGUNA & 1 & 9 & 1443 & 1408 & 2 & 0 & 5 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 53 & 14 & C. A. LAGUNA & 1 & 10 & 656 & 624 & 5 & 0 & 5 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 54 & 17 & C. A. XANXERÊ & 2 & 10 & 434 & 433 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 55 & 18 & C. A. JARAGUÁ DO SUL & 4 & 9 & 180 & 99 & 82 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  56 & 32 & C. A. URUBICI & 2 & 3 & 563 & 562 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\caption{Atendimentos superados (\%)} 
\end{longtable}
```

And here is a image of the result.

[image: tabela]

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Could you post your R source (besides the line you cite) as well?  It looks like your problem is there.

Comment: Where's the image?

Answer (score 1):

Please always post complete documents as below not just fragment. But `\rowcolor` needs to be after the `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,colortbl}

\begin{document}

% Wed Feb 01 15:37:07 2017
\begin{longtable}{rrlrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & CIDADE1 & UOR & MODAL & MES & Atend & Valor & AtSup & Turmas & TurAcu \\ 
\hline
  \rowcolor{red}  
    1 & 1 & C. A. FLORIANÓPOLIS & 2 & 8 & 2725 & 2540 & 7 & 14 & 28 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 2 & 1 & C. A. FLORIANÓPOLIS & 2 & 10 & 2161 & 2126 & 2 & 0 & 28 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 3 & 4 & C. A. BRUSQUE & 1 & 11 & 30 & 27 & 11 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  4 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 6 & 4648 & 2565 & 81 & 0 & 4 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 5 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 8 & 1827 & 1399 & 31 & 0 & 7 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 6 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 9 & 1596 & 1314 & 21 & 0 & 7 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 7 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 10 & 1196 & 1166 & 3 & 0 & 7 \\ 
   \rowcolor{red} 8 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 11 & 1191 & 926 & 29 & 0 & 7 \\ 
  9 & 9 & C. A. CRICIÚMA & 1 & 6 & 233 & 120 & 94 & 1 & 2 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\caption{Atendimentos superados (\%)} 
\end{longtable}



\end{document}
```